# Python XML - accessing attributes from elements within comment blocks

Tags: python, xml

I have an xml document with the following structure:

```
<persons>   
    <person name="John">
        <personattributes>
            <age>32</age>
        </personattributes>
    </person>
    <!-- <person name="Jane">
        <personattributes>
            <age>25</age>
        </personattributes>
    </person> -->
</persons>
```

Note that "Jane" is commented out.

How can I access the attributes from both these elements, such that if I want a list of names I get both John and Jane?

I want to be able to comment and uncomment specific elements using the name attribute, and have written the following code that enables me to comment specific elements and uncomment all nodes.

```
import os
import lxml.etree as ET

tree = ET.parse("filepath")


def comment_element(tree, name):
    for logger in tree.xpath('//theme'):
        if logger.get('name') == name:
            logger.getparent().replace(logger, ET.Comment(ET.tostring(logger)))
    return tree

def uncomment_elements(tree):
    comments = tree.xpath('//comment()')

    for c in comments:

        p = c.getparent()
        p.remove(c)
    return tree



with open("outputfile", 'wb') as f:
            f.write(ET.tostring(tree, encoding='utf-8'))
```

How can I apply the functionality from "comment_element" to the "uncomment_elements" function?